# Sfb asks for password window, when ModernAuthentication is enabled on Office365 tenant, how to handle it programatically?

Tags: c#, authentication, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk, multi-factor-authentication

I have enabled `ModernAuthentication` on `Office365` tenant and my client is `SkypeForBusiness`. I am trying to programatically handle sign-in using `Lync SDK`.

Earlier when `ModernAuthentication` was not enabled, then `BeginSingIn` was able to login to Sfb without any popup for password, however after enabling `ModernAuthentication`, it pops up a window to provide the password.

Please provide me pointers as to how I can handle the new window and pass on the password programatically. I am using C# as the language to do so.

```
_lync.BeginSignIn(username, domainLogin, password, SignInCallback, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Microsoft support:

Unfortunately the Modern Authentication features were not added into the Lync client SDK with consideration for the client SDK.  Therefore there is no programmatic integration with Modern Authentication, and having Modern Auth present will break the client SDK, particularly when the UI Suppression feature is used.

Disabling Modern Auth client side using the EnableADAL registry key can help avoid certain issues, but other items may still break when Modern Auth is present.
These issues were raised to the product team, however their guidance was that the Client SDK and Modern Auth are not supported together.  Their recommendation is to disable Modern Auth for any users which require integration with the Lync 2013 SDK.

Since the Lync 2013 SDK is outside of mainstream support at this time, no future work is planned for it, and so it is unlikely this will change.